# Minimap - Infoscroller does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vue.js

I am trying to use this to make a minimap of a page:

https://github.com/unclenorton/jquery.infoscroller

This demo works just fine:
http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/

However, when I try to implement on my VueJS page, the minimap does not load at all. I only get a spinning loading icon on the side. So what I did was - I downloaded the repo from the Github page and tried to run `index.html` and I am getting the same loading icon.

Here is a screenie of the loading button:

[image: Minimap does not load - spinning loading icon]

I also tried to Save Page as the demo site and run index.html, but I still couldnt make it to work.
Tried to compare the source code of the demo site vs the index.html, they are just the same.

For reference, here are the ff:

- Sample index.html on the Github repo:
  https://github.com/unclenorton/jquery.infoscroller/blob/master/index.html
- Demo Page > View Source: [view-source:http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/](http://view-source:http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/)
- Actual source code of demo site: http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller > Save Page As
  Am I missing anything?

Help!

Comment: "the source code of the demo site vs the index.html, they are just the same." Can you show some code?

Comment: @Kunukn - thanks for the comment, I updated my post with the related links to the source codes

Comment: "when I try to implement on my VueJS page, the minimap does not load at all". There seems to be no code examples of what have been tried? I imagine you would want to include jQuery on the Vue page since jQuery is a dependency to make this work?

Comment: Ah yes, I didnt post my actual code anymore. For simplicity, the index.html from the github page can be used - it exhibits the same behavior. Thanks in advance for your help!